# Sticky div that scrolls to a point

Tags: javascript

I'm very new to JavaScript. My accomplishment is to be able to scroll down to the top of the right div (#aside) and have it be fixed while the other div continues to scroll down.

I've mimicked this code from [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qc4NR/) and added my own id and class but it will not work.

Here is my own [version](https://jsfiddle.net/allison7860/1xz7cnt4/2/)

**HTML (#aside fixed div)**

```
<div id="wrapper">
      <nav>
        <ul class="nav_links">
          <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
          <li><a href="">About</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
<header></header>

    <div id="main">
        <p>Curabitur pellentesque erat feugiat justo euismod, et auctor erat tristique. Duis maximus arcu non nisl placerat cursus eu nec felis. Nunc in suscipit elit. Curabitur nec fermentum dui. Fusce et molestie odio. Mauris mattis commodo risus sit amet
          fringilla. Quisque pretium sem ut est iaculis, a euismod lacus convallis. Fusce porta, justo quis porttitor commodo, justo velit condimentum augue, at tempor nunc dui pretium lacus. Phasellus eget leo neque.</p>
        <p>Ut luctus dictum aliquet. Duis interdum sodales nisl ac egestas. Nunc tempus fringilla risus vel dapibus. In sit amet elit eu felis porta pulvinar. Cras pretium at tellus nec facilisis. Curabitur finibus ut ex eget consectetur. Cras at libero gravida
          velit mollis sollicitudin. Nulla vehicula nisl ut imperdiet tristique. Ut diam justo, condimentum facilisis arcu in, porta feugiat orci. Morbi non venenatis eros. Cras at quam ex. Sed egestas condimentum odio, quis ornare orci.</p>
        <p>Ut luctus dictum aliquet. Duis interdum sodales nisl ac egestas. Nunc tempus fringilla risus vel dapibus. In sit amet elit eu felis porta pulvinar. Cras pretium at tellus nec facilisis. Curabitur finibus ut ex eget consectetur. Cras at libero gravida
          velit mollis sollicitudin. Nulla vehicula nisl ut imperdiet tristique. Ut diam justo, condimentum facilisis arcu in, porta feugiat orci. Morbi non venenatis eros. Cras at quam ex. Sed egestas condimentum odio, quis ornare orci.</p>

        <p>Curabitur pellentesque erat feugiat justo euismod, et auctor erat tristique. Duis maximus arcu non nisl placerat cursus eu nec felis. Nunc in suscipit elit. Curabitur nec fermentum dui. Fusce et molestie odio. Mauris mattis commodo risus sit amet
          fringilla. Quisque pretium sem ut est iaculis, a euismod lacus convallis. Fusce porta, justo quis porttitor commodo, justo velit condimentum augue, at tempor nunc dui pretium lacus. Phasellus eget leo neque.</p>

        <p>Nam malesuada arcu et eros laoreet faucibus. Quisque sit amet lectus ipsum. Ut bibendum, eros et molestie egestas, enim felis iaculis turpis, sit amet consequat sem erat id dolor. Vivamus a leo viverra, viverra odio a, imperdiet dolor. Morbi libero
          neque, gravida ut sem eget, dictum euismod urna. Vestibulum risus ex, venenatis eget fermentum quis, scelerisque eget elit. Phasellus vel sodales urna. Quisque quis tempor ex. Proin sit amet odio eleifend, tempor purus vel, venenatis sem. Vivamus</p>

        <p>Ut luctus dictum aliquet. Duis interdum sodales nisl ac egestas. Nunc tempus fringilla risus vel dapibus. In sit amet elit eu felis porta pulvinar. Cras pretium at tellus nec facilisis. Curabitur finibus ut ex eget consectetur. Cras at libero gravida
          velit mollis sollicitudin. Nulla vehicula nisl ut imperdiet tristique. Ut diam justo, condimentum facilisis arcu in, porta feugiat orci. Morbi non venenatis eros. Cras at quam ex. Sed egestas condimentum odio, quis ornare orci.</p>
      </div>

      <div id="aside">

      <p>Ut luctus dictum aliquet. Duis interdum sodales nisl ac egestas. Nunc tempus fringilla risus vel dapibus. In sit amet elit eu felis porta pulvinar. Cras pretium at tellus nec facilisis. Curabitur finibus ut ex eget consectetur. Cras at libero gravida
        velit mollis sollicitudin. Nulla vehicula nisl ut imperdiet tristique. Ut diam justo, condimentum facilisis arcu in, porta feugiat orci. Morbi non venenatis eros. Cras at quam ex. Sed egestas condimentum odio, quis ornare orci.</p>
      <p>Ut luctus dictum aliquet. Duis interdum sodales nisl ac egestas. Nunc tempus fringilla risus vel dapibus. In sit amet elit eu felis porta pulvinar. Cras pretium at tellus nec facilisis. Curabitur finibus ut ex eget consectetur. Cras at libero gravida
        velit mollis sollicitudin. Nulla vehicula nisl ut imperdiet tristique. Ut diam justo, condimentum facilisis arcu in, porta feugiat orci. Morbi non venenatis eros. Cras at quam ex. Sed egestas condimentum odio, quis ornare orci.</p>
      <p>Ut luctus dictum aliquet. Duis interdum sodales nisl ac egestas. Nunc tempus fringilla risus vel dapibus. In sit amet elit eu felis porta pulvinar. Cras pretium at tellus nec facilisis. Curabitur finibus ut ex eget consectetur. Cras at libero gravida
        velit mollis sollicitudin. Nulla vehicula nisl ut imperdiet tristique. Ut diam justo, condimentum facilisis arcu in, porta feugiat orci. Morbi non venenatis eros. Cras at quam ex. Sed egestas condimentum odio, quis ornare orci.</p>
      <p>Ut luctus dictum aliquet. Duis interdum sodales nisl ac egestas. Nunc tempus fringilla risus vel dapibus. In sit amet elit eu felis porta pulvinar. Cras pretium at tellus nec facilisis. Curabitur finibus ut ex eget consectetur. Cras at libero gravida
        .
      </p>
    </div>

    <footer></footer>

    </div><!--wrapper-->
```

**CSS (#aside and .stick)**

```
.nav_links {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 15px;
}

.nav_links li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav_links a {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 80px;
  color: #000;
}

.nav_links a:hover {
  color: #ada;
  transition: .33s;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  top: 70px;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 35%;
  background-image: url("park1.jpg");
  background-size: 100%;
}

#main {
  background-color: #ded;
  top: 60px;
  width: 60%;
  float: left;
}

#aside {
  float: right;
  width: 30%;
  top: 200px;
  background-color: #ded;
}

.stick {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
}

footer {
  clear: both;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #aaa;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
var aside = document.getElementById("#aside");
var stop = (aside.offsetTop - 210);

window.onscroll = function(e) {
  var scrollTop = (window.pageYOffset !== undefined) ? window.pageYOffset : (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollTop;
  console.log(scrollTop, aside.offsetTop);

  if (scrollTop >= stop) {
    aside.addClass = 'stick';
  } else {
    aside.removeClass = '';
  }

}
```

Comment: "Mimicing" means "Copying" in this case?

Comment: Define "won't work", I don't know what you want to achieve.